# CakePHP 2.0: display associated records

Tags: cakephp, associations, cakephp-2.0

I know the solutions is simple and might have something to do with the Containable behavior but I can't get it working. Without all the tries

This is the case. I'd like to display the Event details of an Event (eg. a conference). Each event takes place in a EventVenue and each EventVenue is located in a Country.

So in the Country Model the following is present:

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'EventVenue' => array(
        'className' => 'EventVenue',
        'foreignKey' => 'country_id'
))
```

In the EventVenue model a BelongsTo association is made

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Country' => array(
        'className' => 'Country',
        'foreignKey' => 'country_id'
))
```

And in the Event model a hasOne association is made

```
 public $hasOne = array(
    'EventVenue' => array(
        'className' => 'EventVenue',
        'foreignKey' => 'event_id',
 ))
```

What I want is to display the country name on the page that is renderd in the EventsController. I do get all the Event and EventVenue data but the associated Country for the venue is not retrieved.

The data is retrieved in the following way

```
 $item = $this->Event->findBySlug($slug);
```

How can I also get the country name (eg. Netherlands) retrieved from the database? I tried something like this but that did not work:

```
 $item = $this->Event->findBySlug($slug,array(
    'contain' => array(
        'Event' => array(
            'EventVenue' => array(
                'Country'
            )
        )
    )
 )
```

Comment: does your event_venues table have a country_id field populated?

Comment: You don't need to contain itself - ie you shouldn't have 'Event' in the 'contain' array (per tyjkenn's answer below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$item = $this->Event->findBySlug($slug,array(
    'contain' => array(
        'EventVenue' => array(
            'Country'
        )
    )
);
```

**Update**

Turns out findBy does not support Containable. You could use this to get the desired result:

```
$item = $this->Event->find('first',array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'Event.slug' => $slug
    ),
    'contain' => array(
        'EventVenue' => array(
            'Country'
        )
    )
);
```

Oh and make sure you have this in the model: `public $actsAs = array('Containable');`

Comment: That will result in the following error:

Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Event.' in 'field list'

And indeed there is no Event Column, only an Event table, and references to an Event are made by a column event_id (that is as far as I know the way CakePHP likes it)

Answer (score 0):

try this method:

```
$this->Event->recusive = 2;
$item = $this->Event->findBySlug($slug);
```

Comment: Recursive 2 is BAD.  Should almost ALWAYS use recursive -1.  Most people I know even set it as the default in the AppModel so you never have to change it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the recursive to 2 before you make the find, something like this

```
$this->Event->recursive = 2;
```

with this, you'll get the Event, the EventVenue and the Country on one shot

Hope it helps